# What is the true meaning of saranagathi and how to perform it?

Tags: vishnu

A lot of scriptures talk about saranagathi. For eg., the charamaslokam of the Bhagavad Gita. Also, the Ramayana talks about it.

It is often translated loosely into english as 'surrender'. However, I feel this english translation does not convey the correct meaning.

What is the true meaning of saranagathi? And how to perform it?

Answer (score 1):

This is from commentary of Baladeva Vidyabhusana, Vishwanath Chakravarty Thakur on Bhagavad Gita 18.66

sarva-dharman parityajya
mam ekam **saranam** vraja
aham tvam sarva-papebhyo
moksayisyami ma sucah

**As per Vayu Purana,**

> anukulyasya sankalpah pratikulyasya varjanam raksisyatiti visvaso
>   goptrtve varanam tatha nihksepanam akarpanyam **sad-vidha saranagatih**
>
> Surrender has six factors: accepting what is favorable, rejecting what
>   is unfavorable, having faith that the Lord will protect one, accepting
>   dependence on the Lord, placing oneself fully to the Lord, and
>   meekness.

**Below are the explanations given by different acharyas:**

As per Baladeva Vidyabhusana:

> Actions pleasing to the Lord that are prescribed by the scriptures are
>   called änukülya or favorable. Opposite actions, displeasing to the
>   Lord, not prescribed by the scriptures, are called prätikülya or
>   unfavorable. Ätma nikñepa means “to place responsibility for ones
>   maintenance in the object of surrender, the Lord.” Kärpaëya means “not
>   bold.” Sometimes the line reads nikñepaëam akärpaëyam. In that case,
>   akärpaëya means “not showing ones miserable position to others.” The
>   rest is clear.

As per Vishwanath Chakravarty Thakur

> Anukulya means conduct pleasing to the Lord and according to the
>   scriptures. Pratikulya means the opposite. Goptrtva means to think of
>   the Lord and no one else as ones protector. One should have faith
>   (visvasah) that in times when ones own existence is threatened, the
>   Lord will give protection, as in the case of Gajendra or Draupadi.
>   Nihksepanam means employment of ones gross and subtle bodies for
>   Krishna’s service. Akarpanya means that  one  should  not  make  a 
>   show  of ones  own  humility.

Below two are from footnotes in the book I referred:

As per Jiva Goswami

> Jiva Goswami explains in Bhakti Sandarbha 236 that goptåtve varanam,
>   accepting the Lord as master, is the very definition of surrender, and
>   is therefore the main item. All other five items are its assistants.
>   Ätmanikñepa means to have no independence from the Lord. “Whatever he
>   orders, I do.” Kärpaëya means complete humility. “No one is more
>   merciful than you, and no one is more fallen than I.”

As per Vedanata Desikan

> Vedänta Desikan takes ätma nikñepa, placing responsibility for ones
>   maintenace in the Lord , as the main item. Goptåtve varaëam is praying
>   for protection, which is similar to rakñayiñyatéte viçvasaù, faith
>   that the Lord will protect one. Kärpaëya is feeling hopeless and
>   incapable, and therefore with humility surrendering to the Lord.